# Google Form response summary url mailed to me onFormSubmit

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-forms

What I need is, whenever a response is submitted to my google form, a url to the summary of that response is emailed to me. And this should happen for every response, so that I have an email for every single response summary.

In my current test form, I have tried the getSummaryUrl() function, in the following ways:

```
1. e.getSummaryUrl();
2. lastFormResponse.getSummaryUrl();
```

both of them don't seem to be working. I am providing my code below

```
function saveDetailsInFolder(e) {
  var lastFormResponse = e.response
  var summary = e.getSummaryUrl();
MailApp.sendEmail({

  to: "My email ID",
  subject: "Test for summary URL",
  body: summary
})

}
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand `Google Form response summary url`, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the method of `getSummaryUrl()` is the method of Class Form. So, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function saveDetailsInFolder(e) {
  var summary = e.source.getSummaryUrl();
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "My email ID",
    subject: "Test for summary URL",
    body: summary
  });
}
```

#### Reference:

- [getSummaryUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getSummaryUrl())